# Why does websocket handshake fail?

Tags: python, websocket

i have the following code for my python server to create and send back the response to an handshake

```
    def HandShake(self, request):
    specificationGUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
    websocketkey = ""
    protocol = ""
    for line in request.split("\n"):
        if "Sec-WebSocket-Key:" in line:
            websocketkey = line.split(" ")[1]
        elif "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol" in line:
            protocol = line.split(":")[1].strip()

    print("websocketkey: " + websocketkey + "\n")
    fullKey = hashlib.sha1(websocketkey.encode("utf-8") + specificationGUID.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    acceptKey = base64.b64encode(fullKey)
    print("acceptKey: " + str(acceptKey, "utf-8") + "\n")
    if protocol != "":
        handshake = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: " + str(acceptKey, "utf-8") + "\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: " + protocol + "\r\n\r\n"
    else:
        handshake = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: " + str(acceptKey, "utf-8") + "\r\n\r\n"
    print(handshake)
    self.request.send(bytes(handshake, "utf-8"))
```

I have tested my method of calculating the key with the example on wikipedia, so i know that is correct. However everytime when i try to connect to my server i get the following the error:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch
```

I dont understand what im doing wrong here. does someone see what is going wrong?

EDIT: an example output from the prints, this prints the original message and the fabricated handshake

```
server started, waiting for connections...
request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:600
Origin: http://localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: yLffHPqMU4gIW2WnKq+4BQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36


websocketkey: yLffHPqMU4gIW2WnKq+4BQ==

acceptKey: A0eCd19URtkji0OPV162okWsCns=

HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: A0eCd19URtkji0OPV162okWsCns=
```

Comment: Post the output of your `print()` calls in your question.

Comment: i edited the op with the print output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your code.

```py
for line in request.split("\n"):
    if "Sec-WebSocket-Key:" in line:
        websocketkey = line.split(" ")[1]
```

That is returning the `"\r"` in your Sec-WebSocket-Key.

Evidence:

**Normal RFC Behavior**

```
Client Key: "yLffHPqMU4gIW2WnKq+4BQ=="
Server Key: YVjKqlMRxlzzM70LScN9VoCsboI=
```

**Bad Behavior**

```
Client Key: "yLffHPqMU4gIW2WnKq+4BQ==\r"
Server Key: A0eCd19URtkji0OPV162okWsCns=
```

Links to [AutobahnPython Sec-WebSocket-Key server side validation](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/99dfdb432ed6d57302d37fe491c647826c681b4e/autobahn/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py#L3095-L3106), and [AutobahnPython hash calculation](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/99dfdb432ed6d57302d37fe491c647826c681b4e/autobahn/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py#L3300-L3306).